# Flutter: Omit else clause in ternary operator in order to use default styling

Tags: flutter, styling, conditional-operator

I am often coming across situations where I would like to style a `Widget` based on some conditional which might look like the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool condition = true;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: OutlinedButton(
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                side:
                    BorderSide(color: condition ? Colors.blue : /** DEFAULT Color**/)),
            onPressed: () => _changeColor(),
            child: Text('Press')),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _changeColor() => setState(() => condition = !condition);
}
```

The above code does not compile as Flutter wants me to specify an alternative color if *condition* is false. But I do not want to specify any color but simply use the **default color set by my `Theme`** in case of *condition* evaluating to `false`. How is this possible?

I know that when using the ternary operator in situations where a `Widget` is to be returned (e.g. after `child: condition ? Container() : ...`), we can simply specify `SizedBox.shrink()` in order to have no effect. What would I do respectively when not wanting to specify any style but fall back to default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

If a property to a constructor to a Flutter widget isn't required, it is generally safe to give it `null` (as that is the default value for any omitted optional property) at which point that widget will either ignore that property or fall back to an implicit default value, whichever is appropriate.

So in this case, your "default" value for `color` can simply be null, at which point the [constructor](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f4abaa0735eba4dfd8f33f73363911d63931fe03/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/borders.dart#L65) for `BorderSide` will fall back to a default value of `Color(0xFF000000)`.

```dart
BorderSide(color: condition ? Colors.blue : null)
```

Comment: I tried using `null` before but this produces the following **runtime error**: `Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/painting/borders.dart': Failed assertion: line 69 pos 15: 'color != null': is not true.)` which makes sense considering the source code of the `BorderSide` constructor `... : assert(color != null)`. If I switch to null-safety, my IDE even shows a **syntax error**. Any ideas how to nevertheless reach the desired outcome? Thank you!

Comment: In that case, you can just use the default that it would've used had you omitted the argument - `const Color(0xFF000000)`.

Comment: Well, that is exactly the problem, I do not know what the exact default color is. It is not 100% black, but some lighter value that changes depending on which `Theme` (light or dark) I use. Is there any table I can use to lookup default colors of Flutter `widgets` to know which property of the `Theme` they refer to (e.g. like  `primaryColor` or `accentColor`)?

Comment: The source code I linked plainly shows that the default color of that property when omitted is 100% black. You can see it yourself by either following the link or right-clicking on `BorderSide` in your IDE and choosing "View implementation" or something similar. Dart/Flutter is open source and at any time you can crack a widget open to see how it is implemented.

Comment: ok, I understand. I hoped there was a way around having to specify anything as I specified a custom `OutlinedButtonTheme` (both for my light and dark `Theme`) which I would like the app to fall back to in case of a `false` condition. But thank you for your help!

Comment: If you have your own custom theme specified, why not just call `Theme.of(context)` and pull the color from there?

Comment: yes, you are right, but I always find it a hassle to figure out the coloring myself and usually I am quite content with the default colors.

Answer (score 0):

In the main file, in MaterialApp, we usually put theme details, where we can also put custom styles if we want to. If we don't put custom theme data, then our app will use default styles.

To get theme value, we need context. We can get any theme value using this.

```
var primaryColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
```

Theme.of(context) has every value of theme style, you can get the default value from here.

Like

```
BorderSide(color: condition ? Colors.blue : Theme.of(context).primaryColor)
```